# Geographic Transformation Qgis

Tags: qgis, qgis-2

How to Define projection and enter the Geographic Transformation parameters from SGL-GEO to WGS84 in QGIS?

Comment: I think this is brand new in QGIS 2.2 : http://sourcepole.ch/ntv2-transformations-with-qgis

Answer (score 1):

1. Define the SGL-GEO projection by clicking the **Settings > Custom CRS** , [image: 1]
2. **Add a new CRS** and add the parameters ,[image: 2]
3. Once you have your SGL-GEO projection defined, go to the **Raster > Projections > Warp(reproject)** and make the tranformation between SGL-GEO and WGS84.

   [image: 3]

Comment: You would include a +towgs84 statement. The transformation values would be dx,dy,dz,rx,ry,rz,ds where the translations are in m, rotations in arc-seconds, and ds is in parts-per-million. Note: PROJ4/GDAL uses the Position Vector versionfor a 7-parameter datum transformation (which affects the rotation values).

Comment: @mkennedy : Isn't the reprojection tool supposed to handle that ?

Comment: I'm assuming SGL = Singapore Land Authority whose transformation parameter values are NOT publicly available and thus must be defined.

Comment: If you're talking about the parameters of the CRS to be defined I should mention that the parameter string I've put in the example is just for the show, it's up to Kwai Hai to write that string.

Comment: I think that's obvious. I just wanted to mention +towgs84 since it's not in the screenshot and it has a 'gotcha' if you're not familiar with its usage.

Comment: Ah great, okay then :)